# Python/pandas: bug in formula evaluation in map/lambda?

Tags: python, dictionary, pandas, lambda

I have experienced a strange issue in python (2.7.6.2) / pandas (0.13, also in 0.18), when applying a formula on a dataframe. Apparently the result of the formula is different when applying with map/lambda, instead of applying directly on the numbers. It seems to be a bug for me, and I would be curious what the reason is respectively how to avoid such issue.

...

I now prepared the case in a way which allows to reproduce it, and this makes the problem somewhat clearer:

```
data15min = [ 5.4753, 5.4863, 5.2497, 5.057, 5.0917, 5.3467, 5.7513, 5.6, 5.342 ]
index     = pd.date_range("2015-10-17 18:00:00", periods=9, freq='15T')
columns = ['v03']

df15 = pd.DataFrame(data15min, index=index, columns=columns)
df_h = df15.rolling(min_periods=4,window=4,center=False).mean()
df_m = df_h['v03'].map(lambda x: np.nan if np.isnan(x) else int(x*100.))
```

The last value from df_h was the value which was calculated wrongly. The value itself looks fine (the mean of 5.3467, 5.7513, 5.6, 5.342 is exactly 5.51):

```
In [99]: df_h
Out[99]: 
v03
2015-10-17 18:00:00 NaN
2015-10-17 18:15:00 NaN
2015-10-17 18:30:00 NaN
2015-10-17 18:45:00 5.317075
2015-10-17 19:00:00 5.221175
2015-10-17 19:15:00 5.186275
2015-10-17 19:30:00 5.311675
2015-10-17 19:45:00 5.447425
2015-10-17 20:00:00 5.510000
```

After applying the formula with map, I get however 550:

```
In [100]: df_m
Out[100]: 
2015-10-17 18:00:00      NaN
2015-10-17 18:15:00      NaN
2015-10-17 18:30:00      NaN
2015-10-17 18:45:00    531.0
2015-10-17 19:00:00    522.0
2015-10-17 19:15:00    518.0
2015-10-17 19:30:00    531.0
2015-10-17 19:45:00    544.0
2015-10-17 20:00:00    550.0
Freq: 15T, Name: v03, dtype: float64
```

I assumed this is due to inaccurate number representation, but I get different behaviour when applying the formula directly on the numbers:

```
In [103]: int(np.mean([5.3467, 5.7513, 5.6, 5.342])*100.)
Out[103]: 551
```

To make the confusion complete, I also get also a different result with map when having a slightly shorter dataframe with the same relevant values:

```
data15min = [  5.3467, 5.7513, 5.6, 5.342 ]
index     = pd.date_range("2015-10-17 19:15:00", periods=4, freq='15T')
columns = ['v03']

df15 = pd.DataFrame(data15min, index=index, columns=columns)
df_h = df15.rolling(min_periods=4,window=4,center=False).mean()
df_m = df_h['v03'].map(lambda x: np.nan if np.isnan(x) else int(x*100.))

In [104]: df_m
Out[104]: 
2015-10-17 19:15:00 NaN
2015-10-17 19:30:00 NaN
2015-10-17 19:45:00 NaN
2015-10-17 20:00:00 551.0
Freq: 15T, Name: v03, dtype: float64
```

I am confused, and concerned about getting wrong results. If this is connected to inaccurate internal number representation (which would be surprising if this issue would behave different for the shown cases), I really wonder how I could avoid getting wrong results from it.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the problem (with my data, since I don't have yours). OTOH your pandas is pretty old.

Comment: I modified the description so that the issue should be easy to reproduce for everyone. I would be very curious to see whether I am the only one who gets wrong results from python/pandas, respectively how to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a floating point accuracy issue. Tha last value in `df_h['v03']` is actually a bit lesser than 5.51:

```
x = df_h['v03'].iloc[-1]
print repr(x)
print repr(x * 100.)
print int(x * 100.)
```

Will print:

```
5.5099999999999989
550.99999999999989
550
```

Of course this is wrong since the actual mean of the numbers as you wrote them is 5.51, but that's how floating point arithmetic works.

IIRC you were trying to use the first three digits as keys in a dict. Just taking the integer part of 100 times the value is a very fragile approach because a very small error may change the result. A more robust one would be rounding to say 3 decimals before:

```
df_h['v03'].round(3).map(lambda x: np.nan if np.isnan(x) else int(x*100.))

2015-10-17 18:00:00      NaN
2015-10-17 18:15:00      NaN
2015-10-17 18:30:00      NaN
2015-10-17 18:45:00    531.0
2015-10-17 19:00:00    522.0
2015-10-17 19:15:00    518.0
2015-10-17 19:30:00    531.0
2015-10-17 19:45:00    544.0
2015-10-17 20:00:00    551.0
Freq: 15T, Name: v03, dtype: float64
```

I guess it will also fail in some corner cases.

Regarding allegedly undeterministic behaviour, there are several algorithms to compute the mean and you shuldn't be assuming that numpy.mean() is being used. Actually it looks like it's not in your case

```
print(x == np.mean([5.3467, 5.7513, 5.6, 5.342]))

False
```

but you can tell pandas to use it:

```
df_h = df15.rolling(min_periods=4, window=4, center=False).apply(np.mean)
x = df_h['v03'].iloc[-1]
print(repr(x))
print(x == np.mean([5.3467, 5.7513, 5.6, 5.342]))

5.5099999999999998
True
```

There is an actual inconsistency in the results of `Rolling.mean()` though:

```
for i in range(6):
    df_h = df15[i:].rolling(min_periods=4, window=4, center=False).mean()
    x = df_h['v03'].iloc[-1]
    print(repr(x))

5.5099999999999989
5.5099999999999989
5.5099999999999989
5.5099999999999989
5.5100000000000007
5.5099999999999998
```

This does not happen if you use `numpy.mean()`:

```
for i in range(6):
    df_h = df15[i:].rolling(min_periods=4, window=4, center=False).apply(np.mean)
    x = df_h['v03'].iloc[-1]
    print(repr(x))

5.5099999999999998
5.5099999999999998
5.5099999999999998
5.5099999999999998
5.5099999999999998
5.5099999999999998
```

I guess `Rolling.mean()` uses some optimisations (maybe reusing calculations from one window to the next one) that introduce further rounding errors and are not used with `.apply()`. It is actually way faster than applying the numpy version:

```
def test1(s):
    return s.rolling(min_periods=4, window=4, center=False).mean()

def test2(s):
    return s.rolling(min_periods=4, window=4, center=False).apply(np.mean)

s = pd.Series(np.random.randn(10000))

%timeit test1(s)

1000 loops, best of 3: 316 µs per loop

%timeit test2(s)

10 loops, best of 3: 84.9 ms per loop
```

This could be due to the overhead of using `.apply()` though. I don't really know much about the internals of this.

Regarding using floats (or values derived from floats) as lookup keys, avoid it if possible at all. Testing them for equality is prone to errors.

If you really need it you can round to the lowest number of decimal places that allows you to tell apart different numbers (in your case 2 decimal places?) and use the rounded value as the key. If you keep the errors small you should not have spurious matches / mismatches.

Keep in mind that there are also several round functions and in particular `math.round()` behaves differently in python2 and python3. I do not think this affects `round()` in numpy or pandas but in any case make sure you are rounding the same way when you create the keys and when you look for them.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I assumed it will be due to inaccurate number representation, but I could not understand why the same values and same formula lead to different results, dependent on context (i.e. the three cases I have shown). 
That was the reason that I first could not explain the problem at all. And this concerns me, because - when testing my code - I usually assume that such kind of problems is deterministic.
Finally, what I want to achive is some kind of lookup table / dict which acts on float values (and is processes quickly). Is there any certain way of doing this?

Comment: @user3967694 It is deterministic if you apply the same function to the same objects, but there may be several functions for the same purpose returning slightly different values, see the edit.

Comment: Thanks. It would not have expected that two ways of calculating a simple mean value could result in slightly differrent values, but finally it is understandable, when considering that the the order of applying operands may influence the numerical inaccuracies. But this does not explain the third example, when applying the same map function on a shorter dataframe. How can also this result be different?

Comment: @emo-martin Yep, the rolling mean for a given window varies a bit depending on the rest of the data. I updated my answer with a possible explanation but I cannot really be sure.

Comment: Goyo, thank you. Very impressing, how you investigate and solve such issue. Now it seems very clear to me, so that I even think I should have discovered it myself. I learned quite a bit, but I am also somewhat sensitized: if such issue can have a noticeable impact on results calculated with a python script, a deep knowledge of possible pitfalls and side effects seems really mandatory.